# Book set in a medieval VR world where the main character goes to the physical server to play for a better connection

Tags: story-identification, books, virtual-worlds

I remember reading the book about 15 years ago. It was full immersion VR in a medieval setting. I've looked at a number of potential matches such as, *Killobyte* or *Heir Apparent* and they don't ring a bell.

I remember one specific detail, the main character would go to the physical server location to play, because she (almost certain it was a she) thought that you would get the best connections if you went local. She's informed later that with modern connections this wasn't necessary. At one point she disconnects and looks around the room expecting to find some kind of culprit there in the room with her, playing local like she is. I think maybe people were starting to die off in real life, and she's trying to help figure it out?

The book was in English, fairly standard sci-fi length (Like *Freedom's Landing* comes to mind).

No recollection on the protagonists age, or the age appropriateness. I vaguely remember a battle scene in game, but don't remember anything beyond it being a medieval setting.

Comment: Tad Williams "Otherland" series? I never got beyond the first book, and think it was multiple settings in a VR environment.

Comment: @Brian I'll read it and see if it rings a bell.

Comment: @brian Finished Otherland. Definitely not the right book/series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe *[A Point of Honor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0886777917)* by Dorothy Heydt (1998).

[image: Front cover of A Point of Honor]

> A world-renowned knight in the virtual reality land of "Chivalry," Mary de Courcy sees her fantasy and real worlds collide when someone attempts to kill her after she wins the virtual manor of St. Chad's-on-Wye.

[The author currently has the book free to download on her site](http://www.kithrup.com/%7Edjheydt/) due to it being out of print.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan. Just seeing a picture of the cover makes me think this is it! I didn't remember the cover before, but seeing it strikes a cord.

Comment: I found out yesterday that with the book out of print, the author has made the book available online for download on their personal website http://www.kithrup.com/~djheydt/.